# Why is a page in my Android app not displaying properly?

Tags: android

I'm writing an Android app. It has two pages. The second page is supposed to be a page full of image buttons. But when I run my app in the emulator and go to the second page, the page is not displayed. Why?

Here's an error I get:

> Android logcat Text :Fatal signal 11(SIGSEGV) at 0X00000000 (code==1) ,thread 614(com.s

THIS IS THE ENTIRE LOGCAT

```
: D/gralloc_goldfish(614): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-14 09:08:14.554: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 89K, 3% free 8141K/8327K, paused 33ms, total 35ms
01-14 09:08:14.584: I/dalvikvm-heap(614): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.998MB for 3145744-byte allocation
01-14 09:08:14.744: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4K, 3% free 11209K/11463K, paused 105ms+15ms, total 160ms
01-14 09:08:15.054: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 3% free 11209K/11463K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
01-14 09:08:15.104: I/dalvikvm-heap(614): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.744MB for 7077904-byte allocation
01-14 09:08:15.254: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 18121K/18439K, paused 97ms+6ms, total 157ms
01-14 09:08:15.424: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3072K, 19% free 15050K/18439K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
01-14 09:08:15.424: I/dalvikvm-heap(614): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.745MB for 3145744-byte allocation
01-14 09:08:15.574: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 18122K/18439K, paused 102ms+15ms, total 149ms
01-14 09:08:15.904: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 18122K/18439K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
01-14 09:08:15.954: I/dalvikvm-heap(614): Grow heap (frag case) to 24.495MB for 7077904-byte allocation
01-14 09:08:16.094: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 25034K/25415K, paused 76ms+6ms, total 140ms
01-14 09:08:16.304: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3072K, 14% free 21964K/25415K, paused 32ms, total 33ms
01-14 09:08:16.314: I/dalvikvm-heap(614): Grow heap (frag case) to 24.498MB for 3145744-byte allocation
01-14 09:08:16.484: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 25036K/25415K, paused 109ms+16ms, total 170ms
01-14 09:08:16.764: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 25036K/25415K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
01-14 09:08:16.814: I/dalvikvm-heap(614): Grow heap (frag case) to 31.248MB for 7077904-byte allocation
01-14 09:08:16.994: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 31948K/32391K, paused 99ms+7ms, total 180ms
01-14 09:08:17.145: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3072K, 11% free 28878K/32391K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
01-14 09:08:17.154: I/dalvikvm-heap(614): Grow heap (frag case) to 31.249MB for 3145744-byte allocation
01-14 09:08:17.314: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 31950K/32391K, paused 82ms+18ms, total 161ms
01-14 09:08:17.624: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 31950K/32391K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
01-14 09:08:17.674: I/dalvikvm-heap(614): Grow heap (frag case) to 37.999MB for 7077904-byte allocation
01-14 09:08:17.874: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 38862K/39367K, paused 108ms+8ms, total 204ms
01-14 09:08:18.024: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3072K, 10% free 35791K/39367K, paused 41ms, total 42ms
01-14 09:08:18.024: I/dalvikvm-heap(614): Grow heap (frag case) to 38.000MB for 3145744-byte allocation
01-14 09:08:18.184: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 38863K/39367K, paused 73ms+20ms, total 157ms
01-14 09:08:18.514: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 38863K/39367K, paused 40ms, total 40ms
01-14 09:08:18.564: I/dalvikvm-heap(614): Grow heap (frag case) to 44.750MB for 7077904-byte allocation
01-14 09:08:18.794: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 45775K/46343K, paused 92ms+21ms, total 228ms
01-14 09:08:18.954: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3072K, 8% free 42704K/46343K, paused 43ms, total 44ms
01-14 09:08:18.954: I/dalvikvm-heap(614): Grow heap (frag case) to 44.751MB for 3145744-byte allocation
01-14 09:08:19.114: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 45776K/46343K, paused 74ms+7ms, total 162ms
01-14 09:08:19.445: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 45776K/46343K, paused 60ms, total 60ms
01-14 09:08:19.445: I/dalvikvm-heap(614): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 7077904-byte allocation
01-14 09:08:19.875: D/dalvikvm(614): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 2% free 45767K/46343K, paused 426ms, total 427ms
01-14 09:08:19.875: E/dalvikvm-heap(614): Out of memory on a 7077904-byte allocation.
01-14 09:08:19.875: I/dalvikvm(614): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
01-14 09:08:19.875: I/dalvikvm(614):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a14568 self=0x2a00b9e0
01-14 09:08:19.875: I/dalvikvm(614):   | sysTid=614 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073870640
01-14 09:08:19.885: I/dalvikvm(614):   | schedstat=( 3996873888 1969503221 492 ) utm=351 stm=48 core=0
01-14 09:08:19.885: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-14 09:08:19.885: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
01-14 09:08:19.885: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
01-14 09:08:19.885: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
01-14 09:08:19.885: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1930)
01-14 09:08:19.885: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
01-14 09:08:19.894: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
01-14 09:08:19.894: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at com.sgs.First.onCreate(First.java:13)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-14 09:08:19.904: I/dalvikvm(614):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-14 09:08:19.914: I/dalvikvm(614):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-14 09:08:19.914: I/dalvikvm(614):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-14 09:08:19.930: A/libc(614): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 614 (com.sgs)
```

THIS IS THE XML CODE

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >




    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/c" />






    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"

        android:src="@drawable/d" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >






     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
         android:layout_width="80dp"
         android:layout_height="300dp"

         android:src="@drawable/e" />






   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"

    android:src="@drawable/g" />





    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"

        android:src="@drawable/f" />

   </LinearLayout>





    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"

        android:src="@drawable/h" />

     </LinearLayout>
```

THIS IS THE CORRESPONDING JAVA FILE

```
package com.sgs;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class First extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);


        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
        ImageView image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);

        image1.setOnClickListener(this);
        image2.setOnClickListener(this);
        image3.setOnClickListener(this);
        image4.setOnClickListener(this);
        image5.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.imageButton1:

        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: put up the complete logcat!!

Comment: Some applicable code wouldn't hurt, either.

Comment: Can't help you if you don't write a complete question with code and log output

Comment: sorry i am new at this , any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: some help any one , please

Answer (score 0):

From the log you can see an out of memory error when an image is beeing decoded:

```
01-14 09:08:19.875: E/dalvikvm-heap(614): Out of memory on a 7077904-byte allocation.
```

Maybe the images used (by mistake) are to large for the memory allocated by you emulator device profile. You could try increasing the heap size of the device  (Window-->AVD Manager-->Virtual Devices-->Edit : Hardware properties)

Comment: 01-14 09:08:19.875: E/dalvikvm-heap(614): Out of memory on a 7077904-byte allocation.